# Qt camera image stays black after adding a QOpenGLWidget

Tags: qt, camera

**Reproducing the issue**

Go to the Welcome page in the Qt Creator and select the 'Camera Example'. Verify that your camera is working properly first by compiling it. Then add a `QOpenGLWidget` in the designer to the `camera.ui` form. Run again, now the webcam should stay black.

Specs:
Windows 8.1
Qt 5.5

This is how it looks like for me:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE2Pe.png

**A little more backstory**

I'm working on a project that requires a video feed to work with OpenGL. I was using a `QAbstractVideoSurface` to get the image data for individual frames. I ran into this issue by just trying to add a `QOpenGLWidget` into the mix to see what happens. I haven't looked further into it yet other than searching for other reports of this. I couldn't find anything specific though.

Comment: cannot reproduce on Linux and Qt 5.5

Comment: Try with a `QOpenGLWidget`. The `QGLWidget` is deprecated and it has some bugs which preclude proper co-operation with other widgets.

Comment: Oh I was actually using a `QOpenGLWidget`, should've checked that a little better. Didn't use Qt in a while. So thanks for the suggestion, edited the OP.